# Play 1.3 JPA model method ".save" took too much time

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, model

I have some problem with multiply saving objects to database; Saving about 7K entries took over 4 minutes.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Entry> entry : dstipmap.entrySet()){
            Long longip = models.Converter.iptolong(entry.getKey());
            DstDBEntry dstDbEntry = dstmap.get(longip);

            if (dstDbEntry !=null){
```

/*cut */

```
                dstDbEntry.date = today;
                dstDbEntry.save();
            } else {
                DstDBEntry dstDbEntry1 = new DstDBEntry(longip, (entry.getValue().bytes).longValue(), (entry.getValue().packets).longValue(), (entry.getValue().flows).longValue());
                dstDbEntry1.save();
            }
        }
```

Is there any more effective method to save all objects as one query?

Comment: you may want to wrap the save operation in one single transaction.

Comment: You could execute JPA native query: `insert into...`.

Comment: Yes, i want to do one single transaction, but i don know how to do it.

Comment: insert into... on every iterate took a lot of time.